# How to sort a single field two different ways in Meteor Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

OK I have a collection of tasks. Some have a `dueDate` and some do not (`dueDate` is missing). Is it possible to sort them, in a single find statement so that the are sorted dueDate asc followed by dueDate missing?

```
// desired sort result
red; 31 oct 2014
blue; 04 nov 2014
green; 15 nov 2015
purple; 
black;
```

Presently if I simply sort by dueDate, asc I get purple and black first. I want to force them to be last.

** EDIT **

I think i can do it if I can create a sort of calculated field called hasDueDate (true/false) then I can sort: {hasDueDate: 1, dueDate:1}. But it seems the only way to compute a field is with aggregation and it's not available from Meteor. Suppose I can set a hasDueDate using a collection trigger . . .

Comment: Rephrasing. So how do you introduce a calculated field into the results? Clearly it needs to be higher than the evaluated date value ( or string, because you are not clear on that ). I think a google search gives you the answer here if you try.

Comment: basically you are right, it seems I can't introduce it in the results unfortunately. so decided on a workaround: introducing it into the doc.

Comment: You can actually introduce that into the results with the aggreation framework. But perhaps (and especially where there is no need to sort this over 1000's of records) what you have done is the correct approach. And most certainly the simplest approach when that is all that needs to be done. Nothing wrong with finding your own answers. Perhaps just a prompt is all you need sometimes. Well done.

Comment: unfortunately aggregation is not available from the Meteor framework (yet!)

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround. Using simpleSchema in Meteor I introduce a new field called `isDueMissing` which is automatically set on insert and update, like a trigger action.

fragment of the simpleSchema for my tasks:

```
  due: {type: Date, optional: true},

  isDueMissing: {
    type: Boolean,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.siblingField('due').isSet) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  },
```

now I can perform the desired sort like this:

```
Tasks.find({done: false}, {sort: {isDueMissing:1, due:1}},
```

[image]